# como reemplazar una cadena con StringBuilder

Tags: java

Buenas tengo un problema con el manejo de `StringBuilder`, el problema es cuando le paso una cadena y reemplazo por posiciones de origen y final, yo quiero que cada vez que reemplazo la misma cadena se mantenga  la original y solo me cambie las posiciones que voy reemplanzando en cada variable.

```
public class PruebaNuevo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder strbNuevo = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("Escribe tu registro");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(sc.nextLine());

        strb.replace(0, 4, "1234");
        System.out.println(strb);

        strbNuevo = strb.replace(34, 37, "AAA");
        System.out.println(strbNuevo);

    }

}
```

La salida es:

```
Escribe tu registro:
13440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Output:
12340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1234000000000000000000000000000000AAA0000000000000
```

Como pueden ver en la segunda cadena se mantiene el cambio de la primera  cadena y también se cambia los 000 por AAA, lo que yo quiero conseguir es que la segunda cadena mantenga  la posición 1344.... pero solo cambien las AAA .

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fíjate que stbNuevo lo inicializas como un StringBuilder vacío, pero luego le asignas lo que hay en strb con la sustitución de las "AAA". Pero como en strb tienes la cadena que empieza por 1234, no te puede devolver 1344 que es lo que esperas.

Para evitar que te pase eso, en vez de inicializar stbNuevo como vacío, lo puedes inicializar al mismo valor que tenga strb **antes de realizar el primer replace** para que mantenga el valor "1344...". Es decir, algo así:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Escribe tu registro");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuilder strbNuevo = new StringBuilder(strb); // ¡ANTES DE MANCILLARLO CON EL REPLACE!

        strb.replace(0, 4, "1234");
        System.out.println(strb);

        strbNuevo.replace(34, 37, "AAA");
        System.out.println(strbNuevo);

    }
```